# Windows 7 firewall and port 7000

Tags: sockets, connection, firewall

I try make PHP Websocket. I found good liblary/example http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket - this good working on my localhost, but in another laptop/computer in this same network not.

I know that this is problem with Windows 7 firewall on server. If I setup exception for port 7000 TCP for send and incoming data - this is not do anything. If I turn off firewall, example from link works perfectly - also form remote (I set up my router).

I have also configured in firewall exception for FTP server, for ports 21 and 20 - works correctly.

Any ideas? I khinked, that is problem with number port 7000, but after turn off windows firewall is OK, works correctly.

Update: 23-04-2015 00:12

I don't understand, but when I setup port 8080 for websocket, this is working, I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use netstat -a -b on your computer before you start your program listening on port 7000.

Here is an example from my PC with Java installed.

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7000           MyPC:0                 LISTENING   [java.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           MyPC:0                 LISTENING   [java.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9999           MyPC:0                 LISTENING   [java.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49157        MyPC:49158             ESTABLISHED [java.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49158        MyPC:49157             ESTABLISHED [java.exe]
  TCP    [::]:7000              MyPC:0                 LISTENING   [java.exe]
  TCP    [::]:8000              MyPC:0                 LISTENING   [java.exe]
  TCP    [::]:9999              MyPC:0                 LISTENING   [java.exe]
```

Note that port 7000 is already in use.  Perhaps this is the problem you are experiencing.